# select random value NOT in array

Tags: javascript, jquery

How would I select a random value (0 to 30) that is not in this array?

```
var list = new Array(1,3,4,7,8,9);
```

Comment: My question was slightly open ended, and I apologize. I am looking for different options, leads.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Build the complementary array and pick random values from it.

```
var list2 = new Array();
for(var i=0; i<30; i++)
  if(!list.contains(i))
    list2.push(i);
```

Then:

```
var rand = list2[Math.floor(Math.random() * list2.length)];
```

Answer (score 2):

```
function RandomValueNotInArray(array)
{
    var e;
    do
    {
        e = Math.random() * 31; // n + 1
    } while (array.contains(e))
    return e;
}
```

Comment: but Math.random will generate float and It should be Math.random()*31?

Comment: The code speaks for itself, but for the sake of completeness consider adding a description

Comment: `Math.random()` returns a decimal value. You need to either `Math.trunc()` or `Math.floor()` the return value before comparing it to a list of integers, otherwise it will never match.

Answer (score 2):

A little recursive function:

```
getNum() {
  let randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * (30 - 1)) + 1
  if (list.includes(randomNum)) {
    return getNum()
  }
   return randomNum
}
```

Might be a little faster, since it first tries to return a random number, and then checks if it's in the array.

Comment: What is the performance like as the number of elements in the exclusion array grows? How does this strategy perform when the possible range grows from 30 to 30,000, and then to 30,000,000?

Comment: Thanks for asking, ran some tests. Used increasing arrays of random numbers and compared recursion to @slaphappy's complementary arr (most voted solution). 

`Parameters(how many generated / how many in array):
(1 in 1000) Recursion ~ 0.015ms / Complementary: ~ 1.25, 1.26 ms
(1 in 10000) Rec ~ 0.030ms / Com ~ 115ms
(1 in 100.000) Rec ~ 0.44ms / Com ~ 11573ms (or crash)
(1000 in 1000) Rec ~ 4 ms / Com ~ 1182 ms
(10.000 in 10.000) Rec ~ 317ms / Com ~ crash 
(1000.000 in 1000.000) Rec ~ 31422ms / Com ~ no way`

Note that recursion can sometimes double its runtime (when it calls itself)!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your list is reasonable small in size, create a list of numbers that are not in the array and then select a number from that array at random.

Answer (score 1):

You need a `while` loop that tests if `rand` is in your `restricted` array and, if so, re-generate a new random number:

```
var rand;
do {
    rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * 31); // re-randomize, 0 to 30 inclusive
} while ($.inArray(rand, restricted) > -1);
return rand;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/dAN8R/

Don't want jQuery? You can replace `$.inArray(rand, restricted)` with [`restricted.indexOf(rand)`](http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/dAN8R/2/) if you use [this polyfill for old browsers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf#Compatibility).

Comment: Isn't this same as this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/6979340/2333214 posted almost 2 years before this..

Comment: @TJ It might be, if `array.contains()` was a built-in method or `Math.random() * 31` wasn't a floating-point number.

Answer (score 0):

I would probably make an array or linked list from which I would subtract the unwanted items. That way I could keep removing items and just randomly select items from position 0 to the array's length - 1 without having to select the same thing twice.

Another way of doing it is to randomize a number between 0 and 30 and to keep doing it while it is found in the array. The only problems with that is knowing when the array is full (to get rid of infinite loops) and that it is a whole lot more processor intensive.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) .

```
var filteredArray = list.filter(function(e){
  return e!= Math.floor(Math.random() * (31));

});
```

Comment: Your code will create a list containing some numbers that are present in the array. The OP wants something quite opposite, only a single number not in the array.

Answer (score -1):

PHP in 2 lines:

```
$result = array_diff(range(1,30), array(1,3,4,7,8,9)); 
echo $result[array_rand($result)];
```

Comment: If this question was tagged as PHP before, it isn't now.

Comment: Just trying to help people arriving here from Google.