# generate random NOT in array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, random

I am trying to generate a random number that does NOT exist in a restricted number array.

js

```
var restricted = [3, 4, 7];

function getRand () {

    rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);

    if ($.inArray(rand, restricted) === -1) {
        return rand;
    } else {
        try again
    }


}

rand = getRand ();
```

Comment: If it is being restricted, it is not very random. Also what is the issue with your current code?

Comment: And, what is your question ?

Comment: I guess he wants us to write the `try again` part?

Comment: Don't re-use `rand` in your function when you're already using it outside the function to hold the return value.

Comment: I think the user is looking to generate a random number outset of a set of random numbers defined in an array, yeah?

Comment: Get a random entry in `[0,1,2,5,6,8,9]`.

Comment: [Duplicate question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6979276/1633510)

Answer (score 3):

If your problem is about how to implement the "try again" part, just call `getRand` recursively:

```
var restricted = [3, 4, 7];

function getRand() {
    var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
    if ($.inArray(rand, restricted) === -1) {
        return rand;
    } else {
        return getRand();
    }
}

var rand = getRand();
```

Also, if all you're using jQuery for is the `$.inArray` method, I suggest using  `Array.prototype.indexOf` instead (for incompatible browsers, a shim is available [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf#Compatibility)).

Answer (score 2):

You need a `while` loop that tests if `rand` is in your `restricted` array and, if so, re-generate a new random number:

```
var rand;
do { 
    rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10); // re-randomize
} while ($.inArray(rand, restricted) > -1);
return rand;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/dAN8R/

Comment: What is wrong with the OP's current code?

Comment: @Neal For starters, "try again" isn't valid code.

Comment: @AustinBrunkhorst no, not in this case.

Comment: @AustinBrunkhorst If `rand` is in the `restricted` array, the test will return some number greater than -1 and we need to generate a new random number.

Comment: May be a little cleaner with a `do-while`. Would prevent the need to seed `rand` with a restricted value.

Comment: @squint true enough; edited.

Answer (score 1):

Try this -

```
var restricted = [3, 4, 7];

function getRand () {
    var gotRand = false;
    var rand;
    while(!gotRand){  // loop until you got random number
       rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
       if ($.inArray(rand, restricted) === -1) {
          gotRand = true;
       }
    }
    return rand;
}

rand = getRand();
```